# Keyboard shortcut (App Shortcut) taken? Cannot use "^Z"

Tags: mac, keyboard, macos, shortcut

When I try to add a Shortcut like this

System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts->App Shortcuts->+->Some title->

I cannot use `^Z` as Keyboard Shortcut.
It is automatically replaced by

1. Shift (illustrated as arrow-up)
   followed by
2. Command (illustrated by the Command key symbol)
   followed by a
3. `Y`

I guess this is because the shortcut is taken. But I couldn't find where. I checked all the other item above "App Shortcuts", i.e. "Accessibility", "Spotlight", ...

How can I check which app is using it and how can I force the system to use my shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a guess… but sounds like something might have a custom map to "Undo" because Cmd/z & Cmd/shift/Y are alternates for Undo.

For it to be auto-replacing inside system prefs would make me think it is not a system key command, but a third party, Karabiner, TypeIt4Me etc

Comment: Yes, you were right. For others having the same problem: check karabiner, and BetterSnapTool